# Sinusoidal curve average decrease between sections - simple but need help

Tags: calculus

New here and would like to ask you clever people something. I have what I’m sure is a simple question and I will look silly asking this but I haven’t done math in over 15 years so I’m really rusty.

I would like to calculate the average y value for certain points bound by a sinusoidal curve.

Now, while I know how to do it over a whole curve (in the attached photo it would be 2/π x 2.5) I don’t know how to do it if I broke the sinusoidal curve up into various sections like shown.

Could anybody help me with finding the average y values (I.e the solid horizontal line on the drawing on the right) for each section?

thanks in advance

Edit: looks like I need reputation points to post a photo so image can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDE0B.jpg

[image]

Comment: I guess you have not provided a link for the drawing.

Comment: Hi. The drawing can be found here: https://imgur.com/gallery/ZpK7znl

Comment: the average value is $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{2.5-2.1}{12-10}=1.2$ If the function is known the average value is: $\frac{1}{b-a}\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx$ See: https://www.mesacc.edu/~marfv02121/readings/average/

Comment: Thanks! The function is just a sin curve. Everyone is congruent with that formula thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, if the function is a sin curve, then sin(10) is either -0.544 (Radians) or 0.174 (Degrees) either values don't match the value of 2.5 you have on the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average for section $A$ is
$$\frac{1}{12-10}\int_{10}^{12} 2.5\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{20}x\right) dx = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(-50)}{\pi}\left(\cos\left(\frac{12 \pi}{20}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{20}\right)\right)\approx 2.459 .$$

Comment: Great thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer of 2.459 is much closer to what i was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The average value of $k\sin{cx}$ between $x=a$ and $x=b$ is $${1\over b-a}\int_a^bk\sin{cx}\,\mathrm{dx}={k(\cos{ca}-\cos{cb})\over c(b-a)}$$

Comment: thank you! The integration was Very useful. It’s been a while since I did it.

Comment: Actually I’m getting -0.08 when I try the above which can’t be right. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Mikeyt Now that I look at the diagram more closely, it appears that your curve is actually $y=2.5\sin{\pi x\over 20}$.  I didn't look at the scale on the $x$-axis before, I guess.  I'll amend my answer in a moment or two.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use the average value formula for a curve:

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\text{d}x$$

This is the same idea behind finding the average value of a finite sequence of numbers, but you're using the integral to find the average value of an infinite sequence (in this case, the sequence is a series of y-values over an interval). This might make a little bit more sense if you look at it in Riemann Sum form:

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x \right)$$

Also, you might find the Mean Value Theorem for integrals helpful:

$$\text{If a function, f, is continuous over [a,b], there exists a number, c, such that:}$$

$$f(c)(b-a)=\int_a^bf(x) \text{d}x$$